# How to make a page as landing page or home page after login in react with sidebar?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have a desktop application in react with login page and several other pages on different routes.

[This is my login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8Vqa.png)

Here is the code for login page

```
import React, { useState, useEffect  } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { login } from "../../slices/auth";
import { clearMessage } from "../../slices/message";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import {toast} from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
toast.configure()


function Copyright(props) {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary" align="center" {...props}>
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link target="_blank" color="inherit" href="https://images.app.goo.gl/dPPQCgKeLKucQVGV7">
        Rekor India Pvt. Ltd.
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const theme = createTheme();

export default function Login(props) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { user: currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);


  const { message } = useSelector((state) => state.message);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(clearMessage());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const initialValues = {
    userid: "",
    password: "",
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    userid: Yup.string().required("This field is required!"),
    password: Yup.string().required("This field is required!").matches(
      /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/,
      "Password must Contain 8 Characters, One Uppercase, One Lowercase, One Number and One Special Case Character"
    ),
  });

  const handleLogin = (formValue) => {
    const { userid, password } = formValue;
    setLoading(true);

    dispatch(login({ userid, password }))
      .unwrap()
      .then(() => {
        if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_STUDENT") {
          props.history.push("/student");
          window.location.reload();
        } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_TEACHER") {
          props.history.push("/teacher");
          window.location.reload();
        } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_CLASS_TEACHER") {
          props.history.push("/class_teacher");
          window.location.reload();
        } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_PRINCIPAL") {
          props.history.push("/principal");
          window.location.reload();
        } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_ACCOUNT") {
          props.history.push("/account");
          window.location.reload();
        } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_ADMIN") {
          props.history.push("/admin");
          window.location.reload();
        } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_MASTER") {
          props.history.push("/master");
          window.location.reload();
        } else {
          props.history.push("/");
          window.location.reload();
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_STUDENT") {
      return <Redirect to="/student" />;
    } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_TEACHER") {
      return <Redirect to="/teacher" />;
    } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_CLASS_TEACHER") {
      return <Redirect to="/class_teacher" />;
    } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_PRINCIPAL") {
      return <Redirect to="/principal" />;
    } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_ACCOUNT") {
      return <Redirect to="/account" />;
    } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_ADMIN") {
      return <Redirect to="/admin" />;
    } else if (currentUser.roles[0] === "ROLE_MASTER") {
      return <Redirect to="/master" />;
    } else {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
  }


  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Grid container component="main" sx={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Grid
          item
          xs={false}
          sm={4}
          md={6}
          sx={{
            backgroundImage: 'url(https://source.unsplash.com/random)',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundColor: (t) =>
              t.palette.mode === 'light' ? t.palette.grey[50] : t.palette.grey[900],
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            backgroundPosition: 'center',
          }}
        />
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={6} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
          <Box
            sx={{
              my: 8,
              mx: 4,
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              marginLeft: '190px',
              marginRight: '121px',
              marginTop: '80px'
            }}
          >
            <Typography component="h1" style={{ fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '50px', lineHeight: '59px', color: '#000000' }}>
              Sign In
            </Typography>
            <br/>
            <div className="col-md-12 login-form">
              <div>
        <Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={handleLogin}
        >
          <Form>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Login Id</label>
              <Field
                margin="normal"
                id="userid"
                label="Login Id"
                autoComplete="userid"
                variant="standard"
                name="userid" 
                type="text" 
                className="form-control" 
                style={{ border: 'none', borderBottom: '1px solid grey' }}
              />
              <ErrorMessage
                name="userid"
                component="div"
                style={{ color: '#FF1616' }}
              />
            </div>
            <br/>

            <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
              <Field
                margin="normal"
                id="password"
                label="Password"
                autoComplete="password"
                variant="standard"
                name="password" 
                type="password" 
                className="form-control" 
                style={{ border: 'none', borderBottom: '1px solid grey' }}
              />
              <ErrorMessage
                name="password"
                component="div"
                style={{ color: '#FF1616' }}
              />
            </div>
            <br/>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs>
                  <Link style={{ color: '#102371', lineHeight: '24px', fontSize: '18px', fontWeight: 'normal', fontStyle: 'normal', textDecoration: 'none', float: 'right' }} href="/forgot">
                    Forgot password?
                  </Link>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <br/>
              <FormControlLabel style={{ color: '#000000', lineHeight: '24px', fontSize: '20px', fontWeight: 'normal', fontStyle: 'normal' }}
                control={<Checkbox id="checkbox" color="primary" />}
                label="Keep me signed in"
              />
              {message && (
                <div className="form-group">
                  <br/>
                  <div style={{ color: '#FF1616', textAlign: 'center' }} role="alert">
                    {message}
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}

            <div className="form-group">
              <Button 
                type="submit" 
                style={{ 
                  borderRadius: '69px', 
                  borderShadow: '0px 4px 14px 1px #949AFF', 
                  backgroundColor: '#3742FA', height: '108px', 
                  fontSize: '25px', 
                  color: '#FFFFFF', 
                  lineHeight: '30px', 
                  fontWeight: '600', 
                  fontStyle: 'normal' 
                }}
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                disabled={loading}>
                {loading && (
                  <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
                )}
                &nbsp;
                <span>Sign In</span>
              </Button>
            </div>
            <Copyright sx={{ mt: 5 }} />
          </Form>
        </Formik>
      </div>
    </div>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

After logging in it is redirecting me to /student route which is correct as per code. But I want to route to /student/home page but with sidebar.

Here is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Login from "./components/Login/Login";
import ForgotPassword from "./components/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword";
import Student from "./components/Student/Layout/StudentLayout";
import MenuState from "./context/Menu/MenuState";
import TeacherLayout from "./components/teacher/Layout/TeacherLayout";
import PrincipalLayout from "./components/Principal/Layout/PrincipalLayout";
import AccountsLayout from "./components/Accounts/Layout/AccountsLayout";
import Register from "./components/Register/Register";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MenuState>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/forgot" component={ForgotPassword} />
            <Route exact path="/student" component={Student} />
            <Route exact path="/teacher" component={TeacherLayout} />
            <Route exact path="/principal" component={PrincipalLayout}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/accounts" component={AccountsLayout}></Route>
            <Redirect to="/" />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </MenuState>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is studentlayout.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import MenuContext from "../../../context/Menu/MenuContext";
import Routes from "../Sidebar/Routes";

export default function Student() {
  const { user: currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  if (!currentUser) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }

  const mycontext = useContext(MenuContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is Routes.js

```
    import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import StudentAssignment from "../Assignment/StudentAssignment";
import StudentExam from "../Exam/StudentExam";
import StudentFee from "../Fee/StudentFee";
import StudentHome from "../Home/StudentHome"
import StudentSubject from "../Subject/StudentSubject";
import StudentTeacher from "../Teacher/StudentTeacher";
import StudentNotice from "../Notice/StudentNotice"
import Layout from "./Layout";

function Routes() {
  
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Route render={(props)=>(
            <Layout {...props}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/student/home" component={StudentHome} />
                    <Route exact path="/student/subject" component={StudentSubject} />
                    <Route exact path="/student/assignment" component={StudentAssignment} />
                    <Route exact path="/student/teacher" component={StudentTeacher} />
                    <Route exact path="/student/fee" component={StudentFee} />
                    <Route exact path="/student/exam" component={StudentExam} />
                    <Route exact path="/student/notice" component={StudentNotice} />
                    <Redirect to="/student" />
                </Switch>
            </Layout>
        )}/>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default Routes;
```

This is my StudentHome.js file

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import AcademicCalendar from "./AcademicCalendar";
import Attendance from "./Attendance";
import HomeWork from "./HomeWork";
import TimeTable from "./TimeTable";
import UpcomingTest from "./UpcomingTest";
import "./Home.css";
import "./StudentHome.css";
import MenuContext from "../../../context/Menu/MenuContext";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function StudentHome() {
  const { user: currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  if (!currentUser) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }
  const mycontext = useContext(MenuContext);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={mycontext.offMenu}
      onScroll={mycontext.offMenu}
      className="stdhome"
    >
      <div
        style={{
          width: "21%",
          height: "100%",
          textAlign: "left",
          padding: "5px 10px",
          alignItems: "center",
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        }}
      >
        <br />
        <span
          style={{
            fontFamily: "sans-serif",
            fontStyle: "normal",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: "25px",
          }}
        >
          Hello,{" "}
          <span
            style={{
              fontFamily: "sans-serif",
              fontStyle: "normal",
              fontWeight: "normal",
              fontSize: "25px",
            }}
          >
            First Name
          </span>
          &nbsp;<span className="wave"></span>
        </span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span
          style={{
            fontFamily: "sans-serif",
            fontStyle: "italic",
            fontWeight: "normal",
            fontSize: "16px",
          }}
        >
          Quote of the day
        </span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span
          style={{
            fontFamily: "sans-serif",
            fontStyle: "normal",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: "16px",
            color: "#636363",
          }}
        >
          "Two to three lines of a quote will fit here perfectly along with the
          name of the author."
        </span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span
          style={{
            fontFamily: "sans-serif",
            fontStyle: "normal",
            fontWeight: "normal",
            fontSize: "18px",
            color: "#636363",
            float: "right",
          }}
        >
          - Name of the Author
        </span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <TimeTable />
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "76.8%",
          display: "inline-flex",
          position: "absolute",
          top: "5px",
          right: 0,
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            paddingTop: "22px",
            paddingLeft: "40px",
            paddingRight: "40px",
          }}
        >
          <div className="div1">
            <Attendance />
            <HomeWork />
          </div>
          <div className="div2">
            <AcademicCalendar />
            <UpcomingTest />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[This is my landing page after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnsq3.png)

I have tried redirecting directly to /student/home, but in that case my home page is coming without sidebar. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c83ND.png) for the same.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? What are you asking for? I would say you just need to redirect to `"/student/home"` instead of `"/student"` but I don't see any `"/student/home"` route being rendered. Is this a [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese as you mentioned, I have already tried redirecting to /student/home. But in that case my home page is coming but without sidebar . I have updated the question with same.

Comment: The root routes don't seem to be allowing for any nested routes since they all only exactly match the URL path. Are you *trying* to navigate to `"/student/home"` and render the `StudentHome` component? Is that the issue, that only `"/student"` is reachable?

Comment: @DrewReese I want to make my StudentHome component as the landing page after login but with sidebar. Currently the scenarios is that I am not able to figure out how to route to StudentHome component with sidebar after login.

Comment: Ok, so ignoring whatever the sidebar is for now (*since it doesn't seem to be anywhere in your code snippets*), where is the code trying to navigate to `"/student/home"`? That's the first step, actually navigating to the target path. From what I see, the code only pushes to one of the root routes. Also, why does the code reload the page and app with `window.location.reload();`? You probably don't want to do this.